# Error when creating scratch org "The processMetadataValues entry for TriggerType has an invalid value."

Tags: salesforcedx, process-builder, metadata-api, scratch-org

I try to create a scratch org, but every time I get the error "The processMetadataValues entry for TriggerType has an invalid value."

```
<processMetadataValues>
  <name>TriggerType</name>
  <value>
    <stringValue>onAllChanges</stringValue>
  </value>
</processMetadataValues>
```

Although no changes have been made to the file in which the error occurs for a very long time.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: are you creating the scratch org from version control or from an org?

Comment: @cropredy from version control

Comment: is there any chance that VCS is outdated compared to a current V53 org?

Comment: @cropredy what do you mean?

Comment: Well, SFDC has been known to change the XML for Flow so maybe your VCS is out of date

Comment: Flow version is 51.0

Comment: Try deploying the FLow from VCS to a sandbox and see what happens

Comment: @cropredy successfully

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to fix this? Since winter '23 we are running into exactly the same issue when trying to deploy our full set of metadata on an empty scratch org. When deploying to a sandbox everything works fine, but there is one single Processbuilder that fails to deploy to scratch orgs with this error.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/185344)

Comment: SFSE is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could keep contributing in such ways to gain enough rep (you only need 29 more - 50 total) to comment under a post, or you could possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you can link to this question for reference (just click "Share" at the bottom left of the post to get a URL).